# :focus-within not working as I want it to

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have this code where I want to click a text, then click another text to change the first text [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfX5h.png). The code is working but it does not update in real-time because the first text goes out of focus when I type. not familiar with focus-within and need a hand.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
  <img id="home-btn" src="icons/home.png" alt="home-btn">
  <button class="presets" id="preset1">preset 1</button>
  <button class="presets" id="preset2">preset 2</button>
  <button class="presets" id="preset3">preset 3</button>
  <button class="presets" id="preset4">preset 4</button>
  <label>
    <input class="presetname" placeholder="Text" spellcheck="false" maxlength="17">
  </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".presets").click(function presets(){
        let preset1 = $("#preset1")
        if ($("#menu #preset1").is(":focus-within")) {
            let presetname = $(".presetname").val()
            preset1.html(presetname)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where did you get `:focus-within` from?  Does seem like it's remotely the correct method to do what you want.

Comment: Can you explain your desired process more specifically?  Don't use "click a text" as that seems it could mean either the button or the input - use "click a button" and "click in the input".  Why do you think you need to check if preset1 has focus?  Your code works fine if you enter text then click the button.  Is that your intended process?  Don't need the focus code for that, just `$(this).text($(".presetname").val());` in the click handler https://jsfiddle.net/uL4x2qmn/  - maybe you don't know about `this` in an event handler so trying to determine which has focus instead of just `this`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. So I have a menu bar that has four presets. I want to be able to rename them with an input (picture in the original post). This does currently work but it does not update unless I click the preset again after typing. I want it to update when the user is done typing in the input. I therefore thought there was a problem with focus and needed to switch to focus-within.